# REST API error code when updating a resource that was deleted in a previous operation

Tags: rest

Let's say we have a PUT(update) operation on a resource that was *already* deleted from the server

What should be the API response code ?

- 4xx - client issue, don't try to send the same query again

or

- 5xx - server issue, the resource couldn't be found on server

or

- **neither of these above ?**

Comment: **404 : Not found** would be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be careful with mapping CRUD operations to HTTP methods. PUT is not an update method. PUT is a request to replace the entity stored under the URI with the entity being supplied. This can be used to update, if the full representation is given (no partial updates with PUT, please) but can also be used to create, when you know the full representation and the resource URI.

So, the answer really depends on the server-side semantics. In principle, if the resource was already deleted and a GET to the same URI would return a 404, then a PUT should recreate it, with the representation supplied.

If that's not desired, and you don't want a client to be able to recreate a resource that was deleted before, then I'd say your deleted resource should return a 410 Gone response code when the client tries a GET on the URI, making it clear that the resource existed at some point but it's not coming back, and an attempt to replace it with a new representation should fail with a 409 Conflict, detailing how the current state doesn't allow that.